# Detect tap on UIImageView inside UIScrollView

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uiimageview, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have a horizontal scrollview filled with `UIImageViews`.

I want to detect a tap on the `UIImageView` and have its background color changed.

Somehow the tap gesture is not working or so.

However, when I add a tap gesture to the scrollview, it works. The `scrollview.background color` can be changed.

But I want to detect a tap on the `UIImageViews` it contains!

```
UIScrollView* scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 50, 768, 127)];
[scrollView setScrollEnabled:YES];
scrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
[scrollView setShowsHorizontalScrollIndicator:NO];
UIImageView *contentOfScrollView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 1, 1130, 125)];
scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(contentOfScrollView.frame.size.width, contentOfScrollView.frame.size.height);

for (int aantal=0; aantal < 6; aantal++) {
    UIImageView *item = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(3+(aantal*188), 0, 185, 125)];
    item.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:item action:@selector(imageTapped:)];
    tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
    tap.cancelsTouchesInView=YES;
    item.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    [item addGestureRecognizer:tap];
    [contentOfScrollView addSubview:item];
}

//UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(imageTapped:)];
//[scrollView addGestureRecognizer:tap];
scrollView.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
scrollView.delaysContentTouches=NO;
[scrollView addSubview:contentOfScrollView];
[self.view addSubview:scrollView];
```

And this is the imageTapped function.

```
-(void)imageTapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gesture
{
    NSLog(@"tapped!");
    gesture.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
}
```

Comment: have replaced < with (smaller than) because the code disappeared thereafter.

Comment: UITapGestureRecognizer's target should be self and not the UIImageView itself.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

User interaction is set to `NO` by default for `UIImageView`, so you need to set it to `YES`.
You set it to yes for "item", but not for `contentOfScrollView`.

Comment: Sounds like this is it. But now I get-[UIImageView imageTapped:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Comment: Oh I had tried initWithTarget:item to try something, but I need to have it set to self. Now it works. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you for your insight! I had read about the user interaction feature and thought I had applied it completely, on the level of the image views as well as the level of the scrollview. But I totally overlooked that middle layer beneath the views and above the scrollview!

Answer (score 1):

Your error is here:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:item action:@selector(imageTapped:)];
```

You need to change the target to "self" instead of "item", then it won't crash.

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(imageTapped:)];
```

Comment: Thank you. However, as you can see, I already had discovered this myself.